# Powershell joining two list files. foreach item in list - if it matches with the name in the other list - to parse together information

Tags: powershell, if-statement, foreach, split

Apologies for the amateur looking code. Maybe I am approaching this wrong? maybe powershell cant do this. I am trying to join 2 lists. 
One list is in a YAML format and has the name of my nodes and other key values. You can see it is missing the description and tag

```
Server1
    nodename: Server1
    hostname: Server1
    description:
    Tag:
    username: svc_acct
    osFamily: windows
Server2
    nodename: Server2
    hostname: Server2
    description:
    Tag:
    username: svc_acct
    osFamily: windows
```

The other lists has the name of the node along with a description and tag. I want to parse through this list, and if the name matches the node, to plug in the labels

```
Name         Desc
Server1      /tag/description
Server2      /tag2/description2
Server3      /tag3/description3
```

This is the code that I have so far. Thank you.

```
$server = get-content -path C:\users\****\Desktop\Servers.txt
$label = import-csv C:\Temp\DandTs.csv


$output = foreach($server in $servers){
            if($label.name -eq $server){
            $tag = $label.desc.Split("/")
            "${server}:"
            "nodename: ${server}"
            "hostname: ${server}" 
            "description:${tag[2]}"
            "Tag:${tag[1]}"
            "username: svc_acct"
            "osFamily: windows"

             }
           }

$output | Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\fullnodelist.txt
```

Comment: Again you replace plural with singular which makes the code really confusing and in this case, the test `if($label.name -eq $server)` will always fail.. The syntax is `foreach ($singleIteratingVariable in $collectionOfThings)`. Please also take a look at the [tour] because up till now, you haven't accepted any of your questions

Comment: Sorry about that. I am still very new and getting used to getting the correct syntax down. Also pretty new to StackOverflow but it has been a great resource and of great help. Many thanks for your feedback!

Comment: It can be hard being new and coming here. You are trying! Everything below ```$Tag =``` is doing nothing but perhaps writing to host in its current shape. I am pretty sure that if you look at the variable ```$servers``` the data there is a mess to parse. pause your script right as it gets into the ```foreach``` and see what ```$server``` has.

Answer (score 1):

If the data in the csv file is like this below and in the script below it is named test2.csv

```
"Name","Desc"
"Server1","/tag/description"
"Server2","/tag2/description2"
"Server3","/tag3/description3"
```

Then this script below works but I am not sure it is going to get you what you want.
I wrote this to point you better. Look at it carefully and draw from the script. Come back if you need more but ask a new and better, more detailed question.
Take that tour mentioned in the comments above.

```
$servers = get-content -path C:\Temp\test1.txt
$labels = import-csv -path C:\Temp\test2.csv


$output = $Servers | ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($label in $labels) {
        if ($label.name -eq $_) {
            $tag = $label.desc.Split("/")
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                Name        = $_
                nodename    = $_
                hostname    = $_
                description = $tag[2]
                tag         = $tag[1]
                username    = "svc_Acct"
                osFamily    = "Windows"
<# These two lines above might be as follows. Depends on your data and if the value changes.
                username    = $label.username
                osFamily    = $label.osFamily
#>
            }
        }    
    }
}

$output | Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\fullnodelist.txt
```

Comment: Sorry I was working on this problem for a while and I guess when it was time for me to ask on StackOverflow, I might have asked it unclearly, I will ask a new question that may be easier to understand. I really appreciate your help though.